# How to write the default translation with react-i18next Trans component, that is valid JSX when using interpolated variables?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to translate a hardcoded text (no i18n) using i18next and react-18next. Because the content I'm trying to translate contains nodes itself, I'm using the Trans component.

I also want to register missing i18n translations automatically, so that it gets properly added to Locize. (I'm using the Locize backend, and it automatically creates missing keys so that I don't have to do it manually)

First, I'll show how I do it using the `t` component, when the content doesn't contain any node.

```
<Heading
  header={t('heading1, `Garant N°{{number}}`, {number})}
>
```

When before i18n I had `Garant N°${number}`, I now have `Garant N°{{number}}`, where `number` is interpolated at runtime. This works perfectly fine with react, and the i18n key `heading1` is automatically added to Locize with `Garant N°{{number}}` as translation for my default language.

---

Now, let's see how I'm supposed to do that with a content that contains node and therefore when Trans must be used:

```
Hello {name}, you can subscribe
<a
  href={'#'}
  onClick={this.doSomething}
>here</a>{' '}
to fetch your discount
```

After i18n:

```
<Trans
  i18nKey={'myKey'}
  values={{
    name: 'John',
  }}
>
  Hello {{name}}, you can subscribe
  <a
    href={'#'}
    onClick={this.doSomething}
  >here</a>{' '}
  to fetch your discount
</Trans>
```

Using `{{name}}` is what's expected by i18next internals to perform the interpolation, but it's not valid JSX, because react will believe `name` is a JS variable, and it'll throw an error at runtime if the variable is undefined, it'll also show in my IDE that the variable is undefined (warnings). And if the variable is defined, it will replace `{name}` by the variable, which will hardcode the default translation. It's not good.

I don't know how to fix this issue, I could use another character for interpolation (instead of `{}`) but that'd require me to update all existing code, which is error-prone and cumbersome + all translations that rely on variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Trans
  i18nKey={'myKey'}
>
  Hello {{name: 'John'}}, you can subscribe
  <a
    href={'#'}
    onClick={this.doSomething}
  >here</a>{' '}
  to fetch your discount
</Trans>
```

should work

Comment: Thank you! That's definitely the easiest way to go, and it would be great to add it to the doc. (the example at https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-with-react-components with `Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>` is **wrong** IMHO, it should be `Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name: name}}</strong>` to make it obvious that's the proper way to do with react.